# How to allow more than one database connection per machine with JBoss 5 and Oracle

Tags: windows, oracle, grails, jboss, grinder

We are trying to reproduce an Oracle deadlock issue in our Grails / JBoss 5 / Windows Server 2003 application with The Grinder. We are simulating 800 concurrent users using 8 VM Grinder nodes, but we are only seen one database connection per VM, so somewhere along the line there appears to be some sort of limit.

How can we lift this limit to allow more than one database connection per VM?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to connect directly from the Grinder to Oracle?  Normally you'd use the Grinder to apply load against your JBoss server, and let JBoss worry about the Oracle connections.

If you really want to go from The Grinder to Oracle, and you want to control exactly how many DB connections you open, it can be done by opening a separate connection for each Grinder threads.  Instantiate a new connection in the **_*init*_** method of your TestRunner class.  You'll want to avoid using any ORM tools (Hibernate, Ibatis, ...) since they do connection pooling for you and won't let you have direct control of the number of DB connections you open.  Use the JDBC API (via jython) instead.

Comment: Hi @Travis, thanks for your answer. We are testing through JBoss instead of directly to Oracle. I'm starting to suspect the 1:1 correspondence between Grinder VM nodes and Oracle connections (through the single JBoss user) was a misread passed on to me. After setting the max-pool-size to 200 and the min-size-size to 40 (the defaults were being used before, I believe 20 and 4 respectively), I was able to personally verify that all 200 connections did eventually get utilized during our load testing.